# Possibility of the existence of Graviphotons?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, carrier-particles, kaluza-klein

I have been attempting to do research on the [graviphoton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviphoton) yet I can find almost nothing, and many of the articles I do find are locked behind hefty paywalls. 
 It is an interesting possibility to think about as, if it exists and could be controlled, would revolutionise our technology and allow extremely fine control over gravity. It could even be used to build a very "sci-fi" esque ship, with graviphotons being channeled into plating to create artifical gravity and negative-gravity graviphotons acting in the walls to counteract inertia. Perhaps it could be used to hold open singularities and create wormholes. Despite this, it seems to be somewhat of a mathematical artifact. 
 If possible could someone give a explanation in layman's terms about what it really is? (in Kaluza Klein or Supergravity.)

Comment: Wikipedia lists in the resources the phd thesis of @CosmasZachos which is an active user on this forum! Surely he'll be of great help

Comment: @DavideMorgante Oh wow! Thank's for the heads up :o

Comment: There is no evidence that such particles exist or can be created. They might; they might not. Physicists theorize about all sorts of particles that do not necessarily have any relevance to the real world.

Comment: @G.Smith Sounds about what I expected. Thanks for the answer : )